# Размещения приложения в app store

Tags: appstore, xcode, ios

Уже близок день когда я опубликую свое первое приложение в App Store. Я уже почти со всем разобрался, осталось уточнить пару вопросов чтобы не было косяков:

1)Я в xcode локализовал свое приложение для английского, русского, немецкого языка. (через project-info-localizacions). Для того чтобы в app store выводилось, что мое приложение поддерживает три этих языка, мне нужно ещё где-то что-то добавлять?

2)В app store обычно пишут, что приложение совместимо с ios начиная 5.0 и оптимизировано под iphone 5. Как выставить начальную версию поддержки ios я разобрался (ios Deployment Target). Но как указать что приложение оптимизировано под iphone 5?

Comment: ЗАБЫЛ САМЫЙ ГЛАВНЫЙ ВОПРОС: промокоды для приложения нужно будет уже при его публикации в itunes создавать, или в xcode тоже что-то надо делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Когда создашь свой ап в itunesconnect , там нужно добавить каждый язык, и описание+мета на нем.

2- Там же когда будешь выкладывать в ITC, указываешь какие устр-ва поддерживаются.

Comment: end все описал верно. Промокоды станут доступны  в itunesconnect после того как приложение пройдет аппрув и получит статус "ready for sale"